# Tax obligations on POD savings bonds

Tags: united-states, taxes, bonds

I inherited series EE savings bonds, my name is in the POD (payable on death).

What taxes am I obligated to pay? I know normally on bond you are taxed on the interest gained. But do I have to pay anything else?

Also can I will these bonds if I don't cash right away, or do I need to do some weird process to change the POD?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://ibd.morningstar.com/article/article.asp?id=698997&CN=brf295,http://ibd.morningstar.com/archive/archive.asp?inputs=days=14;frmtId=12,%20brf295):

> Here's how savings-bond taxation works. Interest on EE Bonds and I
>   Bonds gets added to their initial value until the bonds are redeemed.
>   The difference between the purchase price of the bond and the
>   redemption value of the bond is subject to federal income tax; it is
>   exempt from state and local income tax. Savings-bond holders have a
>   choice about when to pay that tax. One option is to "accrue" it
>   annually, in which case you report the interest and pay tax on it each
>   year. The other is to postpone the tax until the year in which you
>   redeem the bond. (This subject is covered at greater length in IRS
>   Publication 550, "Investment Income and Expenses.")
>
> Most people choose to defer, or delay, the tax. If so, when they die
>   holding savings bonds, there is what's called "income in respect of a
>   decedent," or IRD: income that wasn't taxed before a person's death
>   and would have been taxed if the individual had lived long enough to
>   receive it.
>
> As a result, when inheritors redeem inherited bonds on which the tax
>   has been deferred, they will owe tax on all the interest that has
>   accumulated. If you choose to have the bonds reissued, you have the
>   option of paying tax on whatever interest has accumulated up until the
>   original bondholder's date of death, and then either accruing or
>   deferring any subsequent tax. If you make this decision before the
>   estate is closed, there are a couple of money-savvy ways to have the
>   tax on the IRD paid directly by the estate, rather than coming out of
>   your own pocket.
>
> Report the income to the decedent: This approach makes sense if the
>   decedent was in a lower tax bracket than the bond inheritor, as might
>   be the case when someone dies early in the year or doesn't earn much
>   during the year of death, says Bruce Steiner, a lawyer with Kleinberg,
>   Kaplan, Wolff & Cohen in New York. Or perhaps the decedent had high
>   medical expenses (for example, nursing-home bills) that can be
>   deducted against the income from the bonds. To implement this
>   strategy, you will need the cooperation of the executor (also called
>   the personal representative in some states) or whomever is
>   administering the estate. This person is responsible for filing the
>   decedent's final income tax return, which is due on April 15 of the
>   year after he or she died.
>
> Report the income to the estate: This tends to be a less-attractive
>   option in many cases because an estate hits the highest income tax
>   bracket once it has more than $12,301 of taxable income. (In contrast,
>   a single individual doesn't hit this bracket until her taxable income
>   is more than $413,200.) But to be certain, have tax advisors run the
>   numbers. Often, estate administration expenses can be deducted on the
>   estate's income tax return--assuming the estate is not large enough to
>   be subject to estate tax--and could help offset the income from the
>   bonds, Steiner says.
>
> Note that when an estate is subject to federal estate tax, whoever
>   pays the income tax on the inherited bonds is entitled to an income
>   tax deduction for the portion of the estate tax attributable to the
>   interest on the inherited bonds, Picker says. This could be the estate
>   or an individual beneficiary. They can take this deduction regardless
>   of whether or not, under the will, they are personally responsible for
>   paying the estate tax. If the interest is reported on the decedent's
>   final income tax return, so that it is paid by the estate, that income
>   tax reduces the federal estate tax liability.
>
> Finally, if you choose to have the bonds reissued and then defer
>   future tax, be sure to keep good records of what's already been paid.
>   Otherwise, many years from now when the bond matures or is redeemed,
>   you--or your heirs--could get stuck paying double tax.